# Checking existence of all words words of a column of table 1 in other column of table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains product_name field. Then another table with models.

```
===products
product_id, product_name

===models
model_id, model_name
```

I am looking for a way to do the following.

1. Model names can have words separated by hyphen i.e JVC-600-BLACK
2. For each model I need to check the existence of each words of model in product name.

I'll need result in some where like below.

```
== results
model_id, product_id
```

If someone can point me in right direction, that would be a great help.

**Notes**

1. These are huge tables with about millions of records and number of
   words in model_name are not fixed.
2. words in model may exist in any order or in between or other words in product name

Comment: So you want to look up `"JVC"`, `"600"` and `"BLACK"` in `product_name` for the given example, correct?

Comment: yes and in no particular order

Comment: I think you will need to use FOR XML path to single out every item seperated by the hyphen, and then do a join on to that result set on id's

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that splits the first string into parts using `-` as a delimiter and looks up each part in the second string, returning `1` if all parts were found and `0` otherwise.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.func(@str1 varchar(max), @str2 varchar(max))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos INT, @newPos INT,
          @delimiter NCHAR(1)
  SET @delimiter = '-'
  SET @pos = 1
  SET @newPos = 0

  WHILE (@newPos < LEN(@str1))
  BEGIN
    SET @newPos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str1, @pos)
    IF @newPos = 0
      SET @newPos = LEN(@str1)+1
    DECLARE @data2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @data2 = SUBSTRING(@str1, @pos, @newPos-@pos)

    IF CHARINDEX(@data2, @str2) = 0
      RETURN 0

    SET @pos = @newPos + 1
    IF @newPos = 0
      BREAK
  END
  RETURN 1
END
```

You can use the above function for your problem as follows:

```
SELECT model_id, product_id
FROM models
JOIN products 
  ON dbo.func(models.model_name, products.product_name) = 1
```

It's not going to be fast, but I don't think a fast solution exists, since your problem doesn't allow for indexing. It may be possible to change the database structure to allow for this, but how exactly this can be done largely depends on what your data looks like.

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling I am going to try it out from performance prospective. If that can work within 5-10 mnts I am ok with it. Do you think if I we split model_name into words and save them as records in some other table, would that help. That will allow indexing I think.

Comment: Indexing `model_name` won't really help. You may be able to put a [full-text index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx) on `product_name`, though this probably assumes that, for each word in `model_name`, we're looking for complete word in `product_name`, not just part of a word (e.g. for your example, `JVC 600 BLACKab` won't match since `BLACK` is part of `BLACKab`, not a word by itself). Calling a function is also very likely to prevent using a full-text search. I was considering a recursive CTE, but that may end up being quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution is faster, for you to check if you care:

```
--=======================
-- sample data
-- ======================
declare @Products table
(
    product_id int,
    product_name nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @Products select 1, 'sdfsd def1 abc1klm1 sdljkfd'
insert into @Products select 2, 'sdfsd def2 abc2klm2 sdljkfd'
insert into @Products select 3, 'sdfsd def3 abc3klm3 sdljkfd'


declare @Models table
(
    model_id int,
    model_name nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @Models select 1, 'abc1-def1-klm1'
insert into @Models select 2, 'abc2-def2-klm2'
insert into @Models select 3, 'abc3-def3-klm3'


--=======================
-- solution
-- ======================
select t1.product_id, t2.model_id from @Products t1
cross join (
select 
    t1.model_id, Word = t2.r.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
from (select model_id, x = cast('<e>' + replace(model_name, '-', '</e><e>') + '</e>' as xml) from @Models ) t1
cross apply x.nodes('e') as t2 (r)
) t2
group by product_id, model_id
having min(charindex(word, product_name)) != 0
```

Comment: that seems to be working functionally, but during the process the size of temp database grows above 100GB. I have even tried to make it work on batches of records in model table. but still very slow and consumes lot of memory? Any other suggestion you can make to optimize it?

Comment: @Ankit Sorry, I don't have ideas to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) feature of SQL Server.  In a nutshell, it catalogs all of the words (ignoring noise words like "and", "or", "a" and "the" by default but this list of noise worlds is configurable) in the tables and columns you specify when setting up the Full Text Catalog and offers a handful of functions that allow you to utilize that catalog to quickly find rows.